# Laravel Homestead: "VM not created.. moving on"

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I did a global install of Laravel homestead, edited my `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml`-file and spun up the VM with `homestead up`. Everything worked fine, but then I needed to add another site. I edited `Homestead.yaml` to contain the new project, the tried to run `homestead provision` to apply the changes to the VM. The only thing that outputs is:

```
==> default: VM not created. Moving on...
```

I interpret that as the VM is not running, but it is. The only thing working here is `homestead destroy` followed by `homestead up`, but that (by its nature) detroys the VM's saved state. I though that vagrant commands was applicable to homestead as well, but `vagrant suspend && vagrant up --provision` doesn't help.

So.. How do I apply my new config to an already-existing homestead VM?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### I found the answer at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-2-error?page=1). Copied directly from there:

Try doing this... You should see a vagrant box that is listed that is linked to your composer/vendor...

```
vagrant global-status
```

Example Output:

```
$ vagrant  global-status
id       name    provider   state   directory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1ace413  default virtualbox running (...)/laravel/homestead
```

Then go ahead and run:

```
vagrant provision {ID}
```

Example input:

```
vagrant provision 1ace413
```

ID being the id of the vagrant instance in the above step.

You should then be good to go!

Comment: This, as well as the other answer, do not explain why `*homestead* provision` is not working for the OP, or provide any solutions for that.

Comment: 1) I am the OP. 2) The question was not why it wasn't working: "So.. How do I apply my new config to an already-existing homestead VM?", so yes; this perfectly answers the question.

Comment: Wow I did not realize that, I apologize. I more meant you did not say how to solve your problem with `homestead provision`, but reading the question again and knowing more than I knew yesterday I see that you sort of did.

Answer (score 12):

I recently change my laptop from 32 bit to 64 bit and have to redo installation and setup of my Homestead again.

After setup everything I run below command

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

and I get the same feedback which is

```
==> default: VM not created. Moving on...
```

After that I try this command and all works well.

```
vagrant up
```

I think for first time running Homestead, no need to reload --provision.

Comment: vagrant up is worked for me , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can run `vagrant provision` to update homesteads websites.  However you have to find where the Vagrantfile for the Homestead VM is.  If you did the global install it should be in `.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/` directory.  You need to change into that directory

```
cd ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
```

Then you need to provision the VM

```
vagrant provision
```

Your homestead box should then reflect the changes in the Homestead.yml file.

Edit: I am not at my mac right now so the directory path is a guess of what I remember it being the last time I provisioned my box so please take that into consideration but I am very sure that path should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually though, I already tried that. The exact same output :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had my VM provision vertualbox running
so i had to exit first